# Amount of change in crushing circle to oval

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a formula that will allow me to report the change in a circle to an oval.  At my job we are "crushing" a cut ring of pipe into an oval.  Our supervisor wants to know the % the ring has been "crushed".  Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: When you say % change, what thing do you want a % change for (e.g. do you want the % change in semi-major axis)?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure.  We apply an internal coating to the pipe and he is asking me to report at what point the pipe is bent from its circle shape to an oval shape that the coating begins showing visible cracks or stress.  He has said he wanted a % of bend.

Comment: He hasn't really been precise enough, but {Semi-minor axis} ÷ {Original circle radius} is probably roughly what he's looking for.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a long shot but you could define your change as the proportion by which the circle's [eccentricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)) has increased from zero (by definition) to a number $0 \leq e \leq 1$.

Since both the circle and the ellipse (or *oval* as you put it) are conic sections defined as the locus of points whose ratio of the focus and the directrix are in constant ratio, the eccentricity is this ratio.

For a circle $e=0$. If we define the eccentricity as the function $$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}}$$

Where $a$ is the [Semi-major axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_axis) and $b$ is the [Semi-minor axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-minor_axis). For a circle both the semi-major and the semi-minor axes are equal (to the radius, $r$), rendering the value $e=\sqrt{1-(r^{2}/r^{2})}=\sqrt{1-1}=0$.

For an ellipse, the $a$ and $b$ take different values. Meaning that the above inequality for $e$ holds true.

My advice would be to measure the semi-major and semi-minor axes and compute the eceentricity, this value could be you metric your manager looks for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will have to give us more information on what you mean by this.  At my job we are "crushing" a cut ring of pipe into an oval.  Do you mean just flattening one side? What, exactly, are you given or can measure? Our supervisor wants to know the % the ring has been "crushed".  Percentage of **what**?  The new height as a percentage of the old, or the new cross section area as a percentage of the old?

A circle with radius R has area $\pi R^2$.  If one side is crushed down to r< R, then the height has been reduced to (r/R) (times 100) percent. The new area is $\pi r R$ which is **also** (r/R) (times R) percent.

Comment: We are a internal coating facility of oil and gas pipes.  We cut a section of the pipe in order to place that section in a press.  We then apply pressure to this section of pipe bending it from its original form (circle) into an ellipse.  My supervisor wants to know how much the circle has changed when the coating begins to crack.